# How to fix Programming Error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax)?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using pymysql to fetch data from MySQL database but get this error

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '23:59:00' at line 1")
```

My code is as below

```
cursor1 = price_db.cursor()
cursor1.execute('select * from bo_prices.chart_prices where price_date = {};' .format(string_time)) # Extract 'chart_price' table from price db
data7 = cursor1.fetchall()
chart_price = pd.DataFrame(data7)
```

the string_time is

```
string_time = srt(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2019,10,07), datetime.time(23,59)))
```

How to fix it to fetch the data? Thank you!

Comment: `... where price_date = '{}'` add quotes

Comment: I try to use the ```.format()``` form because the date change everyday, I want the code run automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date value isn't quoted just add single quote to where clause {}

```
cursor1.execute("select * from bo_prices.chart_prices where price_date = '{}';" .format(string_time))
```

Comment: You need to use `"` for the string or escape the `'`

Comment: This solution is not safe and allows SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @KlausD. Solution is just to fix the error in existing posted code. Question isn't about best practices.

Comment: It is always about best practice. You don't give a solution that contains an other serious problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should **not** use string format for SQL queries ever.

You should use substitution.

```py
q = "select * from bo_prices.chart_prices where price_date = '(?)'"
v = (string_time,)
cursor1.execute(q, v)
```

Actually the [documentation of parameter substitution is quite good.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

Comment: Don't need the tuple, can simply use `cursor1.execute(q, string_time)`.